# How do I use an async method to build a List Object?

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, dart, flutter

I am getting an error that says that the method .length is calling on a null object _genreList.

I am using an async method to get data from a local asset sqlite database to which is a list of genre's. Which then I use ListView.builder in order to display that list on the screen. This is the code to obtain the data...

```
Future getGenreData() async {

    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "asset_sample_sqlite.db");

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "sample_sqlite.db"));

    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);

    Database db = await openDatabase(path);

    _genreList = await db.rawQuery('SELECT genre_name[] FROM tbl_genres');

    print(_genreList);

    await db.close();
  }
```

How do I use this method inside the build Widget method so that I can access the _genreList when I use ListView.builder? like so..

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _genreList.length, //need to access the genreList here
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text("${_genreList[index]}"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => BookPage(id: index),
                  ),
                  );
                }
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

The end goal here is to display a list of genres (from the tbl_genres in my sqlite database) that will be able to pass through data to the next page to show a list of books (from the tbl_books in my sqlite database) related to that genre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of programming asynchronously is that your user interface can stay alive while you are doing time consuming work in the background. So you need (and want) to display something like a [`CircularProgressIndicator`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) or even a blank page (e.g. a [`Container`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl5dWKsqvcAhXBAewKHR60DXQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.flutter.io%2Fflutter%2Fwidgets%2FContainer-class.html&usg=AOvVaw3rmSyrM0zmubIk7Ck6lYAP)), while the application is loading.

There are at least these two ways of doing that:

1. Make the widget stateful and introduce a state field `loading`, that you initialize to `true` and set to `false` when your data (in another field) is ready. Your code would look like that:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GenresPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GenresPageState createState() => _GenresPageState();
}

class _GenresPageState extends State<GenresPage> {
  bool loading;
  List<String> genreNames;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loading = true;
    getGenreData();
  }

  Future getGenreData() async {
    final genreData = await actuallyGetThoseNames();

    setState(() {
      genreNames = genreData;
      loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: !loading ? new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: genreNames.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new ListTile(
              title: new Text("${genreNames[index]}"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator(), // or Container()
    );
  }
}
```

2. Use a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). Therefore you would need to refactor your `getGenreData` method to return the list as a `Future<List<String>>`.

Comment: Thanks you so much, this helped out a lot.